# Error in the Github repository ("Couldn't find remote ref main")

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Here I have tried several times to make the same line of code in case I have made some "typo" but I see that it has no effect, I really do not know what to do, I'm a beginner and I just make my first repository on github.

```
MacBook-Air-de-leuxeren:github leux$ git pull -f origin main
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.3' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/leux/.ssh/id_ed25519': 
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref main
```

[Code image in Macbook terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeHH.png)

Comment: Your GitHub repository apparently has no branch named `main` yet. You could use your browser to examine the GitHub repository *on* GitHub and find the list of branch names and commit hash IDs, or run `git ls-remote origin` to have command-line Git show them. My guess at this point is that you told GitHub to make a *totally empty* repository (which then has no commits and no branches in it: it's *empty*...). Until you make some commits and send them *to* GitHub with `git push` it will remain empty. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Meanwhile, as a general rule for StackOverflow, try not to use images when you can cut-and-paste text from the command line. See [ask]. You actually already did the cut-and-paste thing, it just needed a bit of formatting, so I edited your post to use the backquote code markers.

Comment: have you tried `git pull -f origin master`? See also [rename existing branches](https://github.com/github/renaming#renaming-existing-branches).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do:

```
git fetch
git branch -avv
git switch aBranch
```

The [default refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) (`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`) will fetch all remote branches.

Pick one and [switch to it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Comment: ty it actually worked!